# Google Analytics API access without local browser in python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I want to query the Google Analytics API using Python to periodically download data from my Analytics account and store data in a local database. I am basically following the steps as given in the [basic tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api). I am using the [Google client API library for Python](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) in this process.

My script is working fine so far when I am running it on my local dev machine (Mac). When I start the script, my browser opens and I am prompted to grant access to my Analytics data from the app. Afterwards I can run my script as often as I want and get access to my data.

On my server (Ubuntu, only terminal available), the `w3m` browser opens, but I cannot access my Google account from there. I can only quit `w3m` and kill the program with `Ctrl-C`. There is an error message like:

> Your browser has been opened to visit:
>
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=some_long_url&access_type=offline
>
> If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
>   application with the command-line parameter
>
> --noauth_local_webserver

However when I run my script with the parameter `--noauth_local_webserver`, I get the same results - `w3m` opens and I cannot authenticate.

How can I get the `--noauth_local_webserver` to work? I there another way to authenticate without a local browser on the same machine?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I need to automate the authentication process (I don't want to "accept" the API every time). 

Is there any way to send login/password via the python client or will I have to hack the sample codes and do it via PhantomJS?

Comment: phantom js is not a bad idea! I also dont want to accept the API everytime, it ruins automation for me. This looks promising:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/headless-google-auth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `FLAGS = gflags.FLAGS`, you actually need to pass the command-line arguments to `FLAGS` (this may or may not have tripped me up as well :) ). See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/analytics/sample_utils.py#91) for an Analytics-centric example of how to do it (code below as links tend to go away after a while). General idea is that `argv` arguments are passed into the `FLAGS` variable, which then become available to other modules.

```
# From samples/analytics/sample_utils.py in the google-api-python-client source

def process_flags(argv):
  """Uses the command-line flags to set the logging level.

  Args:
    argv: List of command line arguments passed to the python script.
  """

  # Let the gflags module process the command-line arguments.
  try:
    argv = FLAGS(argv)
  except gflags.FlagsError, e:
    print '%s\nUsage: %s ARGS\n%s' % (e, argv[0], FLAGS)
    sys.exit(1)

  # Set the logging according to the command-line flag.
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(getattr(logging, FLAGS.logging_level))
```

Also, turns out that we aren't alone! You can track [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=207) to see when this will get added the documentation.

Comment: Hey, I am also facing the same problem, I am using Google Sheets API, I didn't get your solution, where to put this function, how to call it. I went through the documentation of run_flow from here, https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#commandline, and I am using that correctly. Please help me to understand your solution.

Comment: or else is it possible to get the link from the command line so that i can automate it using seleniumm webdriver to complete the authentication flow.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use GA as a service API:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py
this works perfectly fine. Just remmeber to convert the p12 to an unencryptet PEM file using openssl 
$openssl pkcs12 -in client_secrets.p12 -nodes -nocerts > client_secrets.pem
the import password is printed out when you download the P12 from google developer's console

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and managed to solve it by SSHing into my server. Example:

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 <server-name>
```

I then ran my script through SSH. When I was presented with the URL (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=some_long_url&access_type=offline), I copied and pasted into the browser on my machine to complete the authentication flow.

Comment: Can you explain more... I have the same issue, I have to put it in Amazon Lambda as micro service, so the there is no GUI, I am thinking of accessing a server through SSH and run a selenium automation to open the link that we get, complete the authentication flow... is it possible...

Answer (score 0):

I ran it on my PC, got a token.json, and just copied the token on the server in the home folder (think working directory of the script), it solved it.
No authentication needed if you use same token