# Google Analytics API forces browser open when authenticating in Python

Tags: python, api, google-analytics, ubuntu-12.04

I'm attempting to query data from the Google Analytics API. I've setup my credentials, and I am able to get the following code to run on my Windows local machine. However, when I run from the Ubuntu command line, it forces an SSL browser window to open at the following step:

```
service = initialize_service()
```

All code is below:

```
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run
import sys
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError

CLIENT_SECRETS = 'C:\Users\mds78\Documents\code\google\client_secrets.json'
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = '%s is missing' % CLIENT_SECRETS

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

TOKEN_FILE_NAME = 'analytics.dat'

def prepare_credentials():
    storage = Storage(TOKEN_FILE_NAME)
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
    return credentials

def initialize_service():
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials = prepare_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    return build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)

service = initialize_service()
```

Comment: Have you tried authenticating fully and then running it again? I haven't used the Analytics API, but the behavior with the others is that you need to authenticate first, and the data is stored in `analytics.dat`. The reason you need to authenticate again would be because your `analytics.dat` isn't stored on your Ubuntu machine yet - it only exists locally on your Windows setup.

Comment: thanks that makes a lot of sense. I'm actually having trouble authenticating because entering a username in the SSL is not available (but allows me to enter a password, strangely)...

Comment: Sorry, do you mean SSH or SSL?

Comment: during the process a browser opens saying Viewing[SSL]. apologies as I'm rather new to Ubuntu. Also pretty sure I should not be using credentials = run(FLOW, storage) since that command is meant to prompt a browser.

Comment: Gotcha. There is a flag you can set when running the code (`--no_auth_local_webserver`) that will allow you to authenticate without a browser (see http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/analytics/sample_utils.py#91 for sample code, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956086/google-analytics-api-access-without-local-browser-in-python for a question related to the process). I'm not actually sure what you are seeing, but let's try to the no browser version and see if we can just circumvent the issue :)

Comment: THanks! I just noticed this other stackoverflow. I had tried that option but did not set flags. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem - everything work out?

Comment: It works now, but it still asks me to verify a code (it prompts me to enter a link in an external browser, and then return the key). How often will I need to do this? I'm attempting to run batch reports and so I do not wish to have enter arguments into my program. I'm guessing there is some way to remove human touch.

Comment: Yeah, you want to set the `access_type` parameter of your request to `offline` (so `access_type=offline`). That will allow you to continue to run the program without constantly authenticating.

Comment: thanks. It's a shame there is no way to avoid that entirely. I do not wish to authenticate every time the script runs. It looks like the token generated still has an expiration date of today.

Comment: So if you pass that parameter to the request in your program itself, you won't have to do it every time (I've had some crons running for about a year and have never needed to authenticate).

Comment: I added it to the client_secrets.json file. Within the code that authenticates (above), it references that file. I would assume this is the only place to pass?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22620/discussion-between-rocketdonkey-and-matt)